# Not able to initialize LoudnessEnhancer object in android studio java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to initialize a LoudnessEnhancer class object in Android Studio, but I'm encountering an error with the following code:

```
LoudnessEnhancer loudnessEnhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(0);
```

'0' represents audioSession.Basically, I wanted to apply LoudnessEnhancer to all sounds played by the system.

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVsi4.png)

I have also attached a screenshot of the error. Could someone please help me identify the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.